# How are H.264 Residual Frames Stored and Compressed

Tags: video, compression, video-processing, video-encoding

I am trying to understand better how video compression, specifically mp4 works.

I understand the concept of using motion estimation/compensation to predict a frame. However this leaves behind errors that are stored as residual frames.

There are 2 problems I have when trying to recreate the concepts of storing these residual frames.

**First Problem:** I assume you compress residual frames with image compression like jpg.

If this is true how would you store negative values? To get a residual frame you subtract a predicted frame from an I frame, in some cases subtraction leaves negative numbers.

To illustrate this lets say the I frame pixel is 50 and the P frame is 55:

```
50 - 55 = -5;
```

The difference value is -5. You can't store negative values in a jpg, so I'm guessing you offset it by 127? (The halfway value of 255).

```
50 - 55 + 127 = 122
```

But now you can only record changes up to 127. What if there is a change greater than that? Do you have to record negative values in one jpg and positive values in another?

**My Second Problem**: again assuming you do use jpg to encode residual frames, even a 1920x1080 blank jpg saves at 45kb using the lowest quality settings in photoshop. At 24 frames per second that would put you at 1Mb/s.

So are residual frames broken down even further? Like are only the needed macro blocks saved when a certain error threshold is breached for that block?

Comment: xor, not subtract.

Comment: @szatmary Wow that makes a ton of sense thank you! It looks like mp4 has some impressive motion estimation to compress xor'd frames as small as it does.